# Vaadin 24: tinymce-for-vaadin (Adam Belak version)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm having trouble getting the tinymce editor (by Adam Belak - https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymce-for-vaadin) to show up on my form. I have a very simple form with a list on the left and two textareas - one for the MCE editor and one for the raw text field on the right.

Everything except the MCE field is showing up. There are no compilation errors.

Here's the page code (minus the routine for setting up the grid):

```
@PageTitle("Rich Text")
@Route(value = "rich-text")
@RouteAlias(value = "")
public class AboutView extends VerticalLayout {
    
    @Autowired()
    private final SJNotifConfigDevDataService devDataService;

    Binder<SJNotifConfigDEV> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(SJNotifConfigDEV.class);
    VerticalLayout fieldView = new VerticalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout mainView = new HorizontalLayout();

    private Grid<SJNotifConfigDEV> grid;
    TextArea rawText = new TextArea("Raw Text");
    TinyMceField styledText = new TinyMceField("Styled Text (MCE)");
    
    public AboutView(SJNotifConfigDevDataService devDataService) {
        this.devDataService = devDataService;
        
        setSpacing(false);

        rawText.setHeight("400px");
        rawText.setWidth("800px");
        
        styledText.setHeight("400px");
        styledText.setWidth("800px");
        styledText.setContent("<p>Just a test</p>");

        fieldView.add(styledText, rawText);
        
        mainView.add(createGrid(),fieldView);
        mainView.setSizeFull();
        
        // set the binding
        binder.forField(rawText).bind(SJNotifConfigDEV::getBody, SJNotifConfigDEV::setBody);
        
        // NOT SURE how to set the binder for the MCE field
        //binder.forField(styledText).bind(SJNotifConfigDEV::getBody, SJNotifConfigDEV::setBody);

        H2 header = new H2("Rich Text Editor Test");
        header.addClassNames(Margin.Top.XLARGE, Margin.Bottom.MEDIUM);
        add(header);
        add(mainView);

        setSizeFull();
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
        header.getStyle().set("text-align", "center");
    }
    
    private Component createGrid(){
        grid = new Grid<>(SJNotifConfigDEV.class, false);
        ...
          GRID CODE HERE
        ...

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Here's the POM dependency:

```
<!-- TEXT EDITOR -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.overcoded</groupId>
   <artifactId>tinymce-for-vaadin</artifactId>
   <version>23.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never was able to get it to work. However, another TinyMCE editor (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymce-for-flow) worked just fine.

Code change - **OLD CODE:**

```
TinyMceField styledText = new TinyMceField("Styled Text (MCE)");
```

**NEW CODE:**

```
TinyMce styledText = new TinyMce();
```

Changed the POM dependency to:

```
<!-- TEXT EDITOR -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinymce-for-flow</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also configure the editor with all the options found at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/ by adding a JSON string and setting the configuration of the field:

```
//String tmcoptions = "{\"branding\": false,\"menubar\": false,\"contextmenu\": false,\"toolbar\": false,\"statusbar\": false}";
String tmcoptions = "{\"resize\": false,\"statusbar\": false, \"menubar\": \"tools help\", \"branding\": false, \"plugins\" : \"link image code\",    \"toolbar\" : \"undo redo | styleselect | forecolor | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link image | code\" }";
styledText.setConfig(tmcoptions);
```

Because it's a WebComponent - you can also use your "normal" binding:

```
// binder for the MCE field
binder.forField(styledText).bind(myClass::getBody, myClass::setBody);
```